# JSoup Android Studio Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

I want to use JSoup for get a Spans value, i have not got errors but my app just open and close. If i dont use try-catch the

```
JSoup.connect(url).get()
```

have issue like:

> "Unhandled exception java.io.IOException".

```
package com.example.antalnndor.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
public Document doc;
public String title;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        title = doc.title();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Element span = doc.getElementsByClass("jfg-badge badge-count").get(0);
    TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletext);
    titleText.setText(title);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
//add Exception to method signature
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws IOException {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //don't forget to set timeOut like this
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)timeOut(0).get();
    title = doc.title();

//Element span = doc.getElementsByClass("jfg-badge badge-count").get(0);
TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletext);
titleText.setText(title);
 }
 }
```